# Recursive way of writing SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2

I have table which stores something like a parent-child pair values.
The point to note is that a child can act as a parent of another child.

In the below query, the namekey is the child and the namekeyow (namekey owner) is the parent.

As can be seen from the query, the purpose is to start from a child and find 6 of its ancestors.

```
  SELECT a1.namekey   n1,
                    a1.namekeyow n2,
                    a2.namekeyow n3,
                    a3.namekeyow n4,
                    a4.namekeyow n5,
                    a5.namekeyow n6,
                    a6.namekeyow n7
             FROM   iacira a1
                    LEFT JOIN iacira a2
                           ON a2.namekey = a1.namekeyow
                    LEFT JOIN iacira a3
                           ON a3.namekey = a2.namekeyow
                    LEFT JOIN iacira a4
                           ON a4.namekey = a3.namekeyow
                    LEFT JOIN iacira a5
                           ON a5.namekey = a4.namekeyow
                    LEFT JOIN iacira a6
                           ON a6.namekey = a5.namekeyow
```

Question is, is there some way to do this recursively without these multiple self joins ?

Comment: Look up `CONNECT BY`.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=statement-using-recursive-queries

Comment: Yep, a Recursive CTE will do that.

Comment: platform and version of Db2?

Comment: I do wonder if you even typed "DB2 recursive" in to a search engine...

Answer (score 2):

A recursive CTE takes the form:

```
with
n (namekey, namekeyow, lvl) as (
  select a.*, 1 from iacira a where namekey = 1234
 union all
  select a.*, n.lvl + 1
  from n, iacira a
  where a.namekey = n.namekeyow and  n.lvl <= 6
)
select * from n
```

It can walk the graph in an unlimited number of levels. The query above limits the levels to 6 using `where n.lvl <= 6`.

Comment: Db2 for LUW doesn't support such a syntax. You get [SQL0345N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0250-sql0499#sql0345n) when you try to use JOIN like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vQg338Du). It's better to use alternate syntax to make it work on all Db2 products.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein You are right. I used the wrong syntax for DB2 LUW. It's now fixed (see https://dbfiddle.uk/eC2YV1Be).